# Unable to resolve Gradle sync failure (gradle-4.4) in Android studio 3.1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, android-instant-run

Being new to android studio, I have downloaded android studio version 3.1.3 with gradle build 4.4. Everytime I open android studio, gradle sync starts but never succeeds. This time it throws the following error:

> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

I have tried disabling instant run, but unfortunately in my system there is no way of checking it out.

[image: Instant run can't be disabled]

Rebuild and clear project did not make any changes.

How to sort out this problem as I have a project to be done with android studio?

gradle-wrapper.properties:

[image: gradle-wrapper.properties],

build.gradle:

[image: build.gradle]

Comment: what does the build log say?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work for you.

Change class path 3.1.3 to 3.1.2

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
```

and sync project. as per documentation for gradle version 4.4+ requires plugin version higher than 3.1.0+ and make sure requires internet connection.

Comment: Tried it. But still gradle sync is unsuccessful. Reports the same error again.

Answer (score 0):

Change the gradle version to 3.0.0 and then sync and re build the project. It might help